# How to deploy node express as backend and depoy sveltekit as front on the same host?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sveltekit

sorry i'm new to sveltekit and i don't know how to deploy it with node express as backened on the same host
is it possible to deploy them on the same host ?
or they should be on the separate host for the apis

Comment: You can (and I recommend to) deploy them on the same host. One way is a reverse proxy, e.g. Traefik, nginx, Apache httpd. Another way is to provide the frontend in your backend.

Comment: what you mean provide the frontend in backend ?

Comment: Your backend has routes for the API. You can add a route for the frontend, e.g. [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). You can use Express as a web server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer
first you install the `node-adapter` like this: `npm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-node@next`

And then read the guides from here
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters.
It shows how to set your adaptor to node
here is an example:
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters

Comment: But how do you make it running when run the default `npm run dev`?